# .htaccess redirect non-existing page to custom html keep the current URL

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect non-existing files and directory to my custom page which is error-404.html. I don't want error-404.html to show in the URL instead i want to keep whatever the user inputs in the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error-404.html [L]
```

The code above will keep the URL but when i add "/" in-between, the error-404 page is broken. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

The solution for you is to make **Custom  error with text** , put the flowing code at your main directory `.htaccess` file and you can change the content as you like but make sure

> The text must be wrapped in quotes (") if it consists of more than one word https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<h2>You Are Wrong!!!</h2><a href=/>Go Home</a>"
```

by using this code you will keep whatever the user inputs in the URL as it is if wrong and show only text.

Comment: Hi i appreciate your solution, but the output is not really the one i needed. I want my custom error-404.html file to be shown but retains the user's URL. The solution you suggested will only show a plain text. See below for my new code.                                                                                    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]


   ErrorDocument 404 "<a href=http://example.com/error-404.html></a>"

Comment: it is only sample but you can do whatever , by this way you will show only link to error page , and what you asking to hide error page from url and it cant be like index , that why i give you that suggestion

Comment: I have been stuck with this problem for days. I wasn't every clear but i want to redirect non-existing directory and files to my custom html 404 but i want to retain the users inputted url.

Comment: Show the users wrong request in the url but redirected to my html page.

Comment: ok, this will not happened and the only way what i gave you , why ? because the index page only could display without writing it in url , other pages should be shown by their name , but if you want to show the name of error page + wrong request this is another issue

Comment: the original code i wrote above works, it will redirect to the custom html and keep the wrong url but when i add "/" example. mydomain.com/exa/mple.html it will show the custom html but the page is broken.

Comment: it wiorks fine for me , restart your server and make it again

Comment: I just get what you want want to do ? internally redirect error page ? paste your complete code , because at the code above there is no  RewriteEngine On

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks    
Options -Multiviews    
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.html

Comment: RewriteEngine On     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error-404.html [L]

Comment: yes, but again i will have a broken page when i add "/".